# Can Android application install another application inside of it's own storage space?

Tags: android, mobile, adb

Does anyone know if you can install an apk inside of another apk's storage space? My goal is to create an application which can "house" other applications inside of itself. Or possibly if one application can get the INSTALL_PACKAGES permission (which I believe is reserved by SYSTEM?) could it install applications in a specific location on the device or the SD card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine an application that can just load other applications and install them on your device without your consent. Especially if the loaded application uses different permissions as the "host"-application.

I hope this is not possible. At least not without user interaction!
Otherwise we would be facing severe security leaks and open doors for malware ...

Comment: Maybe let me explain what I had in mind (I agree with you completely):

If we had a "portal" for a certain group of applications, they would require this "storage bin" app wherein all of the data from those apps are housed. The user would obviously go through all the hoops to install these apps. My goal would be when the "storage bin" app is removed, so are the children apps. Currently, it looks like what I want is not possible so I must look for other ways to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same package name for both applications, you could share the storage space.

Comment: If it is the same package name, how does the Android Manifest know that there are two distinct apps?